# I need change browser shortcut url adware

Tags: browser, shortcuts

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWCBb.png]

I have an adware my PC and I need change my all browser shortcuts URL to google. I try manually remove but adware soft set URL again.
I need batch file this operation or vbs script or C# code?

Answer (score 0):

Adware often has a process running that will prevent its removal. For Chrome OS, use a complete Browser Reset: from the *Settings* menu, select *Show advanced settings...*, and then *Reset Settings*.

There are further directions [at Google](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromebook-central/IyNe-hv-Slk) and at [Malware Removal Guides](http://www.malwareremovalguides.info/how-to-remove-adware-from-google-chrome/), but note that *AdwCleaner* is only for Woindows OS using the Chrome browser.

Comment: This looks like Windows OS with the Chrome browser to me